# Locking mouse click on specific region of form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want to lock mouse click for specific time.
I am loading data, at that time i don't want to give permission to click on tab control.

Comment: you, can disable the tab for some time when the Page Loads right.

Answer (score 1):

Put the part which you want to disable in a panel and disable the panel when you want to block the click.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Activate and deactivate the Enabled proprieties of the Panel.

```
            panel1.Enabled = false;
            //               Do whatever you want inside the code
            panel1.Enabled = true;
```